# Does the Wall of Fire spell damage creatures above it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect, 3d-space

The [Wall of Fire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wall-of-fire) spell describes its "damage zone" as:

> One side of the wall, selected by you when you cast this spell, deals
> 5d8 fire damage to each creature that ends its turn within 10 feet of
> that side or inside the wall.

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/145509/66370) discusses whether this is to be understood as a general distance or an outward spread from that side.

What I would like to know is if the damage zone spreads upwards (or downwards) to damage a creature up to 10ft above it or if you can end your turn flying just over the edge of the wall and be unharmed.

Comment: Related question on [Valid wall arrangements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96954/what-are-valid-arrangments-of-panels-for-wall-of-force)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It's ambiguous.

Here's a diagram of the two options, where the blue diamond represents a flying creature that's ending its turn, and we want to know if the blue diamond is on fire or not.

[image: Diagram of the possible wall of fire areas]

This is going to mostly be a question for your DM.  The rules don't make it clear whether they mean "within 10' along a line orthogonal to a point on the wall", or "within 10' of any point on the wall", or something entirely different.

### ...but do you really want to make it complicated?

Personally, while I think the second interpretation is the most clear way to interpret the spell, that actually ends up being a very complicated way to think of the spell *at the table*. Any interpretation of a spell that ends up making me do geometry to figure out what the spell does is probably not a good interpretation.

Realistically, I'm going to use the first interpretation -- a big rectangular space that extends 10' straight out from the wall is *fast and simple*, and speed is what matters most to me when I'm running a game.

Comment: Yes, I did mean to ask if you could end your turn above the wall without risking damage, I edited the question to avoid drawing focus from the important part.

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer to remove the part about jumping.

Answer (score 4):

### Spells do what they say they do.

When cast, the wall of fire burns any creature that ends a turn within 10 feet of one specified side or inside the wall. That designation could be the top or bottom, but choosing so precludes the ability to choose a more traditionally useful front.

The wall of fire does not give warded volume for free. You get one side of warding - if the foe can bypass that volume then they outwitted your spell.

Comment: A very interesting point that the top/bottom of the wall could be selected as the "dangerous" side. One could however argue that nothing prevents the possible volumes from overlap; the top and front sides could share the "diagonal" corner volume.

Comment: @Jave A corner is not a side. But if the DM wanted to allow it then have fun.